# Export query result that contains text with special characters in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, export, export-to-csv, pgadmin

I have a problem with exporting text from Postgres DB, 
I want to export query results to CSV file or any kind of files. The problem is that the text is German and contains also a lot of special characters, and when I use the typical pgAdmin "Download" button, I got the text file but data is inconsistent. I have tried to use the "copy" command to export it using another delimiter "\t" but the situation didn't improve.

Do you have any suggestion of how to export query result with special characters in Postgres and pgAdmin?

Best Regards,